# archives - list of posts divided by month

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to have an archive section in a template with a certain layout.

I am trying to get a list as follows:

```
2011
Desember   (11)
November   (3)
   20-11-2011
   19-11-2011
   01-11-2011
October    (0)
September  (2)
      .
      .
      .
January    (5)
2010
2009
    </code>
```

and i want that for news category

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for any help, and I'm really sorry if this has been asked before.

Answer (score 0):

There's a wordpress plugin that does just that:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/collapsing-archives/
Take a look at this one as well: http://www.viper007bond.com/wordpress-plugins/clean-archives-reloaded/